# Can I initiate one Django model object inside another

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class User (models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    joined_on = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_name

class Note (models.Model):
    msg = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.msg[:40]
```

These are my django models.

Now, I get the data for models using a Django Form. All I want to do is push them into database. The below is the code I am doing.

```
u = User(user_name="my name")
n = Note(msg="hi", user=u)
n.save()
```

Now, I am getting `IntegrityError: note_note.user_id may not be NULL` error.

However, I do just `u.save()` its not showing this error (there is still a RuntimeError Warning for datetime)

This is what I am looking to build:

1. Create a contact form where user_name, email, url, msg are fields (email, url not mandatory)
2. push the data to db.

where I am going wrong and how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID of a new object is not defined until it has been saved. Save the User object first and then save the Note object.

Comment: Actually, let me first..can you tell me about this `blank=True, null=True` arguments, what should be exactly those considering my requirements

Comment: The Django docs are an excellent resource. Here's the info you are looking for: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/

Answer (score 1):

blank:

If True, the field is allowed to be blank. Default is False.

Note that this is different than null. null is purely database-related, whereas blank is validation-related. If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank